# Water heater in garage with respect to garage dimensions of building code (California)

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, building-regulations

I am considering the relocation of my water heater which currently resides in a recessed platform in my garage, out into the garage area. A new raised platform would be 24" square and be located in the same corner.

Plumbing and vent seem to be easily refactored to support this move, however what building codes should I be aware of prior to this project?

A. The 18" raised platform requirement for fuel ignition, but my water heater is FVIR and I believe not subject to this.

B. The need to protect against mechanical damage but would like clarification on this requirement. The code states:

> Appliances installed in garages, warehouses, or other area subject to mechanical damage shall be guarded against such damage by being installed behind protective barriers **or by being elevated** or located out of the normal path of vehicles. (CPC 507.13.1)

Can I meet this requirement by elevating the water heater on a similar height platform in the garage? *Normal path of vehicle* is also somewhat ambiguous. Is this corner in the "normal" path of a vehicle?

C. Seismic bracing, T&P, etc. of course are doable in this new location.

D. Is there a more general garage dimension I may be encroaching on by moving the appliance into the new location?

What else am I missing? And, do the requirements change at all if I install a tankless on this same wall at an elevated height?

Crude drawing below, with the existing location on top and the proposed location on bottom:

[image]